# Do I need a disclaimer for a camera in a private restroom?

Tags: united-states, recording

I will be leasing an apartment. Because maintenance personnel will be entering when I am not home, I plan to setup cameras throughout the apartment. I have confirmed this is not a lease violation to use cameras inside the apartment. However, what about the restroom? I am aware of laws regarding the expectation of privacy in a public restroom. However, how do these apply to a private restroom? Do I need a posted disclaimer of some sort? Thank you.

Comment: It may be helpful to include what state you're in, since the relevant laws/regulations are almost definitely state-dependent (between you being a lessee, private bathroom, etc).

Answer (score -6):

I'm sure this will get voted down since everyone on here just wants to quote 9 Supreme Court Cases instead of getting a right answer, but you are free to record your own bathroom if you like.

You want to be careful as to where you point it though. If you video tape people in the various stages of undress you could get in trouble.

If it is pointed in a way that it would not reasonably catch someone nude, it is fine.

Comment: Told you about the senseless downvotes.

Comment: I think it was starting with an insult directed at other users, or maybe the implied "9 supreme court cases say one thing, I say another, but I'm right".

Comment: No one argued with the court. I said instead of answering a specific question they want to quote court cases.

Comment: @Putvi you do understand that in common law jurisdictions, decisions of the court are the law?

Comment: I never said otherwise and have been to court lol.

Comment: I'm not sure how this got to me saying that the court can't make decisions, but ok lol.